# How to use numeric(0) in greater than testing?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, numeric

I'm running a greater than test (see below) in a for loop:

```
if(x > y){...}
```

but at one point y will become numeric(0) while x will still be a numeric.  So I need to know if there is a way to still test if a number is greater than numeric(0).  This is the error message I get when I do it:

```
Error in if (x > y) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there a way to test it or even a way to substitute just plain 0 for numeric(0) in this case?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with `tryCatch`. Post your code and I'll show you how

Comment: `numeric(0)` (or any zero length vector) can be identified by checking it's `length`, which will be 0.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Not sure what I was thinking on that one. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is supposed to happen when you compare a number with an empty value? Should the  condition x > y evaluate to TRUE or FALSE, or should there be a different effect? One way to handle the situation is like this:

```
if (length(y) == 0) {
    cat("y is numeric(0)")
} else {
    if (x > y) {
        cat("x is greater than y")
    } else {
        cat("x is less than or equal y")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, depending (as BigFinger wrote) on what you want the branching to be,

```
if(length(x)>0 && x>y ) {do_your_stuff}
```

I am assuming here that your `x` and `y` are scalars. Otherwise, you'll need to be a lot more careful, as   `if` doesn't accept a multiple-valued outcome.

Comment: One problem with `&&` is that it silently takes the first element of a vector of length greater than 1.  `if` gives a warning message.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg yep, hence my warning.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are always scalars or `numeric(0)`, and if `numeric(0)` is equivalent to 0 in your problem, then you can write

`if(sum(x) > sum(y)){...}`

or leaving `x` without the `sum` if you know it can never become `numeric(0)`.

This works because `sum(numeric(0))` gives `0`.

I haven't tested whether this is faster than implementing an `if` that checks the `length` of `y`, but I believe it should be faster (and more concise).